# JPasswordField addFocusListener not working correct keeps repeating message

Tags: java

I have a login form with 2 JTextFields - one "elbtUser" the other "pass" (username and password) and everything works. I want to show a message as shown below if username is left empty and pass is clicked else the button will enable. It works but the message keeps repeating in an endless loop. How to I get back to form break out?

```
pass.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
        if(elbtUser.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "username cannot be empty");    
        }
        else {
            btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for 100% certainty, but I'm guessing after the dialog is closed the text field regains focus and triggers the action listener.  If this is the case, try 1 of two things:

1) add a variable to keep state and when the dialog *should* be shown.  Once on focus gained, and then it should be reset when elbtUser gains focus.

2)  You can force elbtUser to request focus after dialog is shown, elbtUser.requestFocus();

//edit.. i Just tried (1) as it seemed easier and it works,

```
        pass.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            if(elbtUser.getText().equals("")) {

              //do this *BEFORE* displaying the dialog!!!
                elbtUser.requestFocus(false);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "username cannot be empty");

            }
            else {

            }
        }
    });
```